# Python: how to close a socket cleanly to avoid 'can not assign requested address' error (high frequencies)

Tags: python, c, sockets, server, frequency

I have a server on localhost running in c.
I am not sure if showing the related code would be relevant here (it was strongly inspired from  https://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part2/chap6/simple-server.c)

On the same machine, I have a python client which code is the following:

```
import socket,sys,struct,time,threading,random

from frequency_counter import Frequency_counter

# careful ! must be same as c counter parts                                                                                               
SL_PORT = 862
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
REQUEST_CODE = -1

INT_SIZE = struct.calcsize('i')
FLOAT_SIZE = struct.calcsize('f')


class _open_socket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        #self._socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)                                                               
        #self._socket.bind(('localhost',0))                                                                                               
        self._socket.connect(('localhost',SL_PORT))
    def __enter__(self): return self._socket
    def __exit__(self,type,value,trace): self._socket.close()


def send_floats(*floats):
    with _open_socket() as socket_:
        packed_data = struct.pack('i'+'f'*len(floats),len(floats),*floats)
        packed_data = packed_data+'0'*(BUFFER_SIZE-len(packed_data))
        socket_.sendall(packed_data)

def receive_floats():
    with _open_socket() as socket_:
        packed_data = struct.pack('i',REQUEST_CODE,)
        packed_data = packed_data+'0'*(BUFFER_SIZE-len(packed_data))
        socket_.sendall(packed_data)
        data = socket_.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        nb_received = struct.unpack('i',data[:INT_SIZE])[0]
        received = struct.unpack('f'*nb_received,data[INT_SIZE:INT_SIZE+nb_received*FLOAT_SIZE])
        return received


if __name__ == "__main__":

    freq_counter = Frequency_counter()

    while(True):
        floats = [random.random() for _ in range(50)]
        send_floats(*floats)
        received = receive_floats()
        freq_counter.tick()
        print "frequency : ",freq_counter.get()
        #time.sleep(0.001)
```

This code runs at very high frequency (around 5000Hz) for a few seconds, then the frequency decreases over a couple of seconds to around 500Hz, and finally the line 'self._socket.connect ...' throws the error 'Cannot assign requested address'.

Reducing the frequency by adding a call to time.sleep did not solve the issue (just, things run longer before the exception is thrown).

Investigating about what was going on I found this:
https://idea.popcount.org/2014-04-03-bind-before-connect/

Apparently, all the ports in the "ephemeral" range get used (?). And apparently, closing the opened sockets does not help (?).

Following the suggestion of the document above, I started using the SO_REUSEADDR option (commented code in class open_socket).
The error was not thrown, but the frequency started varying with periods at 4000Hz and periods at 40Hz (the latest being not acceptable for my needs).

Is the approach just not suitable for very high frequency exchange, or is there anything I could do ?

edit : tried to call the 'shutdown' function before closing the socket, on both server and client side. Did not change anything.

Comment: how many sockets is the python client process creating ?
if you are using a linux system you can do something like `lsof -p PID | wc`
giving you a rough idea about that. The range of ephemeral ports in most of the linux systems is defined in a config file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` you can cat the file and check your the total number that you can use, also you can increase the number of ephmeral port by a simple echo to the file if you have root prvilages

Comment: @cmidi it created 56478 sockets

Comment: Try adding `__del__` to your socket class?

Comment: @cmidi but increasing the range would just postpone the time at which no port are available ?

Comment: @SeanPedersen Tried that, no effect --;

Comment: yes but in any case for a given ip address the socket structure can only hold 2 bytes i.e 16 bits i.e upto 65535 port numbers it is going to get exhausted anyways until you use `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option.
In any case you can increase it by `echo "1000 65001" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`

Comment: @cmidi thanks, I will try that. But any idea how to avoid the bumps in frequencies ? I guess there is no simple answer to that, but why can't the port of a closed socket by immediately reused ?

Comment: Tcp sockets have different states and timeouts before the resource is completely freed and ready to be reused this might help http://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg

Comment: Well, if you desire high-frequency exchanges, not continually opening and closing the socket seems like a good plan.

Comment: @MartinJames I was trying that right now. For some reason super unclear to me, frequency dropped to a steady 25Hz when using a single socket.

Comment: In addition to that try using non blocking sockets and have some event handling loop to handle the wouldblock errors

Comment: OK, now disable nagle.

Comment: thanks for your help ! Problem is solved, I write details in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments to the question, a solution was found:

- First, the c part was relevant. When data was sent to it, it was not sending anything back. I did not get at that time it was mandatory. I guess as a result the related sockets were not closed, hence difficulties to find novel ports for new sockets. Having the c side always answering solved the issue.
- Disabling nagle allowed to get from 3000Hz to 4000Hz. It was done as following.

c side:

```
int nodelay_flag = 1;
setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void*) &nodelay_flag, sizeof(int));
```

python side:

```
socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
```

- reusing the same socket (rather than creating a new one for each data transfer) raised the frequency to a whooping 11000Hz. It required (limited) modifications to both C and Python side. I guess the side effect of that is that only one client can connect to the server, but that is ok for my needs.